# Getting started with zend framework

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I am trying to start with zend. I followed this guide.I am using wamp.
http://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/user-guide/skeleton-application.html
It says all the dependencies will be installed and yes I see framework in the vendor folder after the installation. I configured the virtual hosts how he told me to. But I just can't get started. It gives me Internal server error. Tried to access it using localhost/zf2-tutorial . But I dont see any public folder. I just don't know where I am doing wrong. Please help me

Comment: What does the logs tell you?

Comment: what logs? where will it be?

Comment: OK, this said: Before you start with a framework, you should make yourself familar with the language and the runtime (here: including the webserver). You _could_ start directly with a framework, but having problems with _everything_ is very frustrating. However: The webserver logs usually under `/var/log/xy.log`

Comment: If you are referring to apache error log...I got following errors.But I can't make out any thing out of it.

Comment: C:/wamp/www/zf2-tutorial/public/.htaccess: Invalid command 'RewriteEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration

Comment: client denied by server configuration: C:/Apache2, referer: http://localhost/zf2-tutorial/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> C:/wamp/www/zf2-tutorial/public/.htaccess: Invalid command 'RewriteEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration

(See comment of the question)

Next time, please google for the error message ;) However, it tells you, that `mod_rewrite` is either not installed, or enabled. On Linux it's like

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

and restart server. I see, you are using Windows, but I must say I don't know ;) I fear you'll find very much about this problem, when you look around, because it's a quite common problem.

Comment: Best place to get started with a tutorial... http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/learning.quickstart.intro.html